# CircleCI getting an error on running a make command

Tags: makefile, yaml, circleci

I want to config.yml that has a "build" and "test" jobs.
We have a `Makefile` in our docker image but it seems it's not finding the make file since I'm always getting this error

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
make test
make: *** No rule to make target 'test'.  Stop.

Exited with code exit status 2
CircleCI received exit code 2
```

Is anyone familiar with this? I'm not sure what I have missed.
Thank you!

Here is the yml file:

```
version: 2.1
workflows:
  my-workflow:
    jobs:
      - build:
          context: circleci-aws-credentials
      - test

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:11-jdk

    working_directory: ~/my-project

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          key: my-project-service-{{ checksum "./build.gradle" }}

  test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:11-jdk

    working_directory: ~/my-project

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

    steps:
      - run:
          name: Gradle test
          command: make test
      - store_test_results:
          path: ./build/test-results
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I would guess that the directory you think you're in (where `Makefile` lives) is not the directory you are actually in when you run the `make` command.  I don't know enough about docker and whatever tool you are using to run that yaml file but are you sure that the `working_directory: ~/my-project` is doing what you think?  Does it support expanding the `~` character?  Does your docker image have a user account with a home directory containing the `my-project` directory?  If you add a step that prints `pwd` and/or `ls` to show the setup during the test does it show what you expect?

Comment: @MadScientist hi sir. thank you for your comment! I just realized that what i was missing is the `- checkout` step.

Comment: @MadScientist really appreciate your time!